# How to know the path of a running executable?

Tags: files, process, executable

I am working on a Linux server, and I running different jobs on different node.

However, when compiling my program, I didn't set their specific name, so they are all `a.out`

Now I found one of the running `a.out`, may be not right, and want to terminated. But the `Top` command doesn't show the path to the executable.

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) (available for just about any Unix variant, but often not part of the default installation) to list all the files a process is using. “Using” includes open file descriptors as well as closely related concepts such as which executable the process is running. The executable has `txt` in the FD column, for [obscure historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282506/where-did-the-text-segment-get-its-name).

```
$ lsof -p1234 | grep txt
a.out    1234 user15964  txt   REG  253,0  34567 /path/to/a.out
```

(made-up output)

On Solaris and Linux, there's a more direct way: the [proc filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) provides information about each process, including which executable it's running. (On Linux at least, that's where `lsof` gets its information.)

```
$ ls -l /proc/1234/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 30 34:56 /proc/1234/exe -> /path/to/a.out
```

If you're looking for a process running a given executable, run [fuser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)).

```
$ fuser /path/to/a.out
/path/to/a.out: 1234e 1239e
```

Comment: Wow, you answer provide more info. Thank you so much. I decide to accpet yours

Answer (score 5):

There's no general answer. Under modern Linux, you can look in `/proc/$PID` where `$PID` is the numerical process ID. You can get it out of the `top` output.

`ls -l /proc/$PID/exe` will show you where `exe` is a symbolic link to. That's the full path to the `a.out` executable.

Comment: Seems like that *is* a general answer, for Linux (which this question is tagged as)....

Comment: It's worth knowing that `/proc/$PID/exe` [isn't a standard symlink](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197901/135943).

Comment: But, I tried "ls -l /proc/28363/exe", it says  no such file or folder

Comment: @user15964, what OS are you using?  Does `ls -l /proc` show anything?

Comment: @Wildcard yeah, ls -l /proc shows a list. I am on RedHat linux

Comment: @Wildcard Oh, sorry, I type the wrong pid. Thank you so much! This solve the problem

Comment: so, there is no way to let `ps` show the contents of /prod/$PID/exe right? I was looking for such option but couldnt find it on `ps`, or I missed something?