# permission denied, even when I have permission

Tags: bash, permissions, proc

This may be a dumb question, but how does symbolic link preserve permission?

```
$ls -ld /proc/1/exe
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/1/exe': Permission denied
```

so I look up what the link point to with `sudo`:

```
$sudo readlink -f /proc/1/exe
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
$ls -ld /usr/lib/systemd #check if r+x for the dir to traverse it
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4.0K May 18 19:34 /usr/lib/systemd/  #yes I do
```

So I do have rx permission for others, but with symbolic link `/proc/1/exe` I cannot read the dir (traverse it) without `sudo`. Why?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197854/how-does-the-proc-pid-exe-symlink-differ-from-ordinary-symlinks

Comment: Well, then it could be marked as duplicated, but does not have to get downvote immediatelly

Comment: it's not an exact duplicate, hence suggesting as related, not duplicate.  (not the downvoter).  The core idea that `procfs` is it's own thing and doesn't necessarily follow all the rules expected from other filesystems still applies, but I haven't dug out the detail of where `EACCES` comes from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "good" (i.e. conforming to all the relevant standards) way of achieving what is desired here (showing only some but not all of the content (metadata) of a directory).

But the kernel does tell you that you have no permissions on this object if you ask it:

```
$ test -r /proc/2072/exe ; echo $?
1
$ test -w /proc/2072/exe ; echo $?
1
$ test -x /proc/2072/exe ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Ok, that is basically, what I have tried. But is there a explanation or rational behind this? (Why does `procfs` behaves differently compared to other filesystems mounted on the OS?)

Comment: @Herdsman Usually only the content of files is considered confidential. But it can be necessary to protect the names of files (in this case: the targets of symlinks). The location of these symlinks cannot be moved to a protected directory because they are expected there. The parent directory cannot get protected because then the access to files would be blocked which must not be blocked.